# R user-defined/dynamic summary function within dplyr::summarise

Tags: r, function, dplyr, non-standard-evaluation

Somewhat hard to define this question without sounding like lots of similar questions!

I have a function for which I want one of the parameters to be a function name, that will be passed to dplyr::summarise, e.g. "mean" or "sum":

```
data(mtcars)
  f <- function(x = mtcars,
                groupcol = "cyl",
                zCol = "disp",
                zFun = "mean") {
    
    zColquo = quo_name(zCol)
    
    cellSummaries <- x %>%
      group_by(gear, !!sym(groupcol)) %>% # 1 preset grouper, 1 user-defined
      summarise(Count = n(), # 1 preset summary, 1 user defined
                !!zColquo := mean(!!sym(zColquo))) # mean should be zFun, user-defined
    ungroup
  }
```

(this groups by gear and cyl, then returns, per group, count and mean(disp))

Per my note, I'd like 'mean' to be dynamic, performing the function defined by zFun, but I can't for the life of me work out how to do it! Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match.fun` to make the function dynamic. I also removed `zColquo` as it's not needed.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

f <- function(x = mtcars,
              groupcol = "cyl",
              zCol = "disp",
              zFun = "mean") {

  cellSummaries <- x %>%
                   group_by(gear, !!sym(groupcol)) %>% 
                   summarise(Count = n(), 
                             !!zCol := match.fun(zFun)(!!sym(zCol))) %>%
                   ungroup

  return(cellSummaries)
}
```

You can then check output

```
f()

# A tibble: 8 x 4
#   gear   cyl Count  disp
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1     3     4     1  120.
#2     3     6     2  242.
#3     3     8    12  358.
#4     4     4     8  103.
#5     4     6     4  164.
#6     5     4     2  108.
#7     5     6     1  145 
#8     5     8     2  326 

f(zFun = "sum")

# A tibble: 8 x 4
#   gear   cyl Count  disp
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1     3     4     1  120.
#2     3     6     2  483 
#3     3     8    12 4291.
#4     4     4     8  821 
#5     4     6     4  655.
#6     5     4     2  215.
#7     5     6     1  145 
#8     5     8     2  652
```

Comment: thanks! Any reason that match.fun() is better or worse than get()?

Comment: I think it's just a matter of choice. I usually use `match.fun` for functions.

Comment: Cheers, accepting this one as you were first! Seems like there are a few ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `get`

```
library(dplyr)    
f <- function(x = mtcars,
            groupcol = "cyl",
            zCol = "disp",
            zFun = "mean") {


  zColquo = quo_name(zCol)
  x %>%
  group_by(gear, !!sym(groupcol)) %>% # 1 preset grouper, 1 user-defined
  summarise(Count = n(), # 1 preset summary, 1 user defined
            !!zColquo := get(zFun)(!!sym(zCol))) %>% 
ungroup
 }

f()
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#   gear   cyl Count  disp
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1     3     4     1  120.
#2     3     6     2  242.
#3     3     8    12  358.
#4     4     4     8  103.
#5     4     6     4  164.
#6     5     4     2  108.
#7     5     6     1  145 
#8     5     8     2  326 


f(zFun = "sum")
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#   gear   cyl Count  disp
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1     3     4     1  120.
#2     3     6     2  483 
#3     3     8    12 4291.
#4     4     4     8  821 
#5     4     6     4  655.
#6     5     4     2  215.
#7     5     6     1  145 
#8     5     8     2  652
```

---

In addition, we could remove the `sym` evaluation in `group_by` and in `summarise` if we wrap with `across`

```
f <- function(x = mtcars,
            groupcol = "cyl",
            zCol = "disp",
            zFun = "mean") {



 x %>%
    group_by(across(c(gear, groupcol))) %>% # 1 preset grouper, 1 user-defined
    summarise(Count = n(), # 1 preset summary, 1 user defined
            across(zCol, ~ get(zFun)(.))) %>% 
    ungroup
 }
f()
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#   gear   cyl Count  disp
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1     3     4     1  120.
#2     3     6     2  242.
#3     3     8    12  358.
#4     4     4     8  103.
#5     4     6     4  164.
#6     5     4     2  108.
#7     5     6     1  145 
#8     5     8     2  326
```

Comment: thanks! Any reason that match.fun() is better or worse than get()?

Comment: @dez93_2000 You could pass unquoted `sum` or `mean` in `zFun` and then you don't need any other function i.e. `zFun(!!sym(zCol)))` should work

Comment: thanks again. Never thought of using get() for functions! Your across() approach is interesting - I'm still getting my head around that new implementation.

Comment: @dez93_2000 thanks.  With `across`, you can pass multiple functions, to blocks of columns, and by default, it will return with the same column name.  Thus, some of the evaluations can be simplified

Comment: That was what most appealed when I heard about it; what's intriguing me is 1. why does using across in group_by obviate the need to !!sym() the groupcol, and 2. that second use of across is top tier wizardry! Is the tilde purrr style? Is seems like across(zCol, get(zFun)) should work??

Comment: @dez93_2000 In `summarise` you can use multiple columns like `summarise(across(c(Zcol, Zcol2), ~ get(zFun)(.))`. The `~` is for lambda function `function(x)`

Comment: @dez93_2000 yes, it would work without the `~`.  I used it just to make it more flexible in case you want to add more parameters and it is more readable