# R, dplyr: Using dynamic variables to access a table name

Tags: r, dynamic, dplyr

I'm trying to use dynamic variables in a for loop to access a tablename.  Other questions on SO (eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083907/how-to-call-an-object-with-the-character-variable-of-the-same-name), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-dplyr) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62906259/r-user-defined-dynamic-summary-function-within-dplyrsummarise)) seem to be about using dynamic variables to access a column name. I'm using R v4.0.3 and dplyr v1.0.2.

Basically, I'm importing from a .sav (SPSS) file, and seeking to split the 400+ columns into smaller dataframes holding the info for each survey question. That part works, but I then want to do things like add a mean column for each new dataframe. I'm currently trying to do that in the segmentation for loop, but I can't get it to work.  (I'd also be happy to do it separately for each new dataframe in another for loop or a list or something, but I can't see how that would work either if I can't get the other one to work!)

Simplifying somewhat, the columns in the original file are named as QX.Y_Z, where Z are items within question Y in the X block.

Some dummy data, setting up a (sav-type) dataframe of 2 questions, each with two items:

```
    mydata=tibble(Q6.1_1_1=as.numeric(c(2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)),
              Q6.1_1_2=as.numeric(c(1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2)),
              Q7.1_1_1=as.numeric(c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2)),
              Q7.1_1_2=as.numeric(c(3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3)),
              )
    var_label(mydata$Q6.1_1_1)<-"Rate your effort - before."
    var_label(mydata$Q6.1_1_2)<-"Rate your effort - before." 
    var_label(mydata$Q7.1_1_1)<-"Rate your enthusiasm - before." 
    var_label(mydata$Q7.1_1_2)<-"Rate your enthusiasm - after." 
    val_labels(mydata$Q6.1_1_1)<-c(Low=1, Medium=2, High=3)
    val_labels(mydata$Q6.1_1_2)<-c(Low=1, Medium=2, High=3)
    val_labels(mydata$Q7.1_1_1)<-c(Low=1, Medium=2, High=3)
    val_labels(mydata$Q7.1_1_2)<-c(Low=1, Medium=2, High=3)
```

```
mydata
# A tibble: 14 x 4
     Q6.1_1_1   Q6.1_1_2   Q7.1_1_1   Q7.1_1_2
    <dbl+lbl>  <dbl+lbl>  <dbl+lbl>  <dbl+lbl>
 1 2 [Medium] 1 [Low]    1 [Low]    3 [High]  
 2 1 [Low]    3 [High]   2 [Medium] 1 [Low]   
 3 3 [High]   1 [Low]    1 [Low]    3 [High]  
 4 1 [Low]    1 [Low]    2 [Medium] 1 [Low]   
 5 2 [Medium] 1 [Low]    1 [Low]    2 [Medium]
 6 3 [High]   2 [Medium] 3 [High]   1 [Low]   
 7 1 [Low]    3 [High]   3 [High]   3 [High]  
 8 3 [High]   3 [High]   1 [Low]    2 [Medium]
 9 2 [Medium] 1 [Low]    2 [Medium] 3 [High]  
10 1 [Low]    3 [High]   3 [High]   1 [Low]   
11 1 [Low]    1 [Low]    2 [Medium] 3 [High]  
12 1 [Low]    1 [Low]    1 [Low]    1 [Low]   
13 2 [Medium] 1 [Low]    3 [High]   1 [Low]   
14 2 [Medium] 2 [Medium] 2 [Medium] 3 [High]
```

Remove the item number from the question string:

```
varlist<-mydata %>% 
  colnames() %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  separate(value, "qno", sep="_", extra = "drop", fill="right") %>%
  unique() %>% 
  pull()
```

```
> varlist
[1] "Q6.1" "Q7.1"
```

Generate the subtables:

```
for (v in varlist) {
  assign(paste0("table", v), select(mydata, matches(v)))
}
```

This gives me subtables called tableQ6.1 and tableQ7.1.  So far, so good.

However, when I try to add a mean column (giving the mean of each row) for each of these subtables as they are generated, I can't find a way to tell mutate() to use the dynamic name of the table.  These are a couple of the options I've tried, but all I get (with these and a LOT more) is errors, so I must be missing something obvious:

```
for (v in varlist) {
  assign(paste0("table", v), select(mydata, matches(v)))
  tabname<-sym(paste0("table", v))
  mutate({{tabname}}, mean=rowMeans(across(where(is.numeric)), na.rm = FALSE))
}

for (v in varlist) {
  assign(paste0("table", v), select(mydata, matches(v)))
  tabname<-"table{v}" %>%
    mutate("mean{v}":=rowMeans(across(where(is.numeric)), na.rm = FALSE))
}
```

Any guidance (including wider comments on whether this is the best approach) would be welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `split.default` to split dataframe with similar column names and then take row wise mean of each subset. This would avoid you to create intermediate dataframes and variables.

```
sapply(split.default(mydata, sub('\\..*', '', names(mydata))), rowMeans)

#       Q6  Q7
# [1,] 1.5 2.0
# [2,] 2.0 1.5
# [3,] 2.0 2.0
# [4,] 1.0 1.5
# [5,] 1.5 1.5
# [6,] 2.5 2.0
# [7,] 2.0 3.0
# [8,] 3.0 1.5
# [9,] 1.5 2.5
#[10,] 2.0 2.0
#[11,] 1.0 2.5
#[12,] 1.0 1.0
#[13,] 1.5 2.0
#[14,] 2.0 2.5
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I think I need to create the subtables to allow for analysis at the question level, plotting of data, and so on.

Comment: @donnek `subtables <- split.default(mydata, sub('\\..*', '', names(mydata)))` This is where your subtables are. It is better and easier to manage if you keep them in a list instead of creating objects in global environment.

Comment: Aaah, I see what you mean.  I get a list of lists, the latter being the dataframes for each question.  I can access those ```subtables$Q6```, ```subtables[["Q6"]]``` or ```subtables %>% pluck("Q6")```, but is there any way to pass a list of questions (eg ```c("Q6", "Q7", "Q12")``` to the subtables list and get the columns for those questions?  I can't seem to get the right invocation for that - obviously a lot of learning to do on lists!

Comment: You can do `subtables[c('Q6', 'Q7', 'Q12')]` to get multiple lists.

Comment: Yes, but that just gives a subset of ```subtables``` - I was trying to get the columns in that subset in one dataframe.

Comment: You can do `lapply(subtables[c('Q6', 'Q7', 'Q12')], colnames)` Or `sapply(subtables[c('Q6', 'Q7', 'Q12')], colnames)`. Are you sure all these questions are part of your original post?

Comment: Haha!  That **was** my original question: "However, when I try to add a mean column (giving the mean of each row) for each of these subtables as they are generated, I can't find a way to tell mutate() to use the dynamic name of the table."  Thanks for your help.